# Удаление строки из таблицы с подзапросом к той же таблице в MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

Пытаюсь настроить удаление из таблицы строки по значению не-ключевой колонки (значения в ней могут повторяться, но это приемлемо).

Я знаю, что в безопасном режиме работы MySQL Workbench таблицы в MySQL меняются только по ключевым столбцам, поэтому, немного погуглив, попробовал схитрить и сделать подзапрос к той же таблице.

```
delete from tcontrol where id in 
(
    select * from 
    (select id from tcontrol where name like '123') t
);
```

MySQL Workbench на это всё равно ругается и заявляет, что не может сделать такого при безопасном режиме удаления. Отключать этот режим не хочется.

Есть ли какой-то обходной путь?

Comment: Первый мой комментарий был верхом тупизма, попробую реабилитироваться: в чем проблема с простым `DELETE FROM tcontrol WHERE name LIKE '123'`?

Comment: В том же. Столбец name не ключевой, поэтому Error code 1175.

Comment: @Etki видимо, в safe mode (о котором я узнал 7 минут назад) так нельзя делать. Непонятно только зачем его использовать и в это же время пытаться его обойти. Проще тогда его отключить.

Comment: Вы часом не из mysql workbench сидите?

Comment: Часом да. Вырубил safe mode, теперь заработало в самом простом (вашем) варианте. Насчёт того, какие будут последствия, пока не знаю.

Comment: Никаких. Это тулза в том числе для офисных работников, которая по умолчанию ведет себя параноидально.